# Julia - @spawn computing jobs sequentially instead of parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, multicore

I am trying to run a function in parallel in Julia (ver. 1.1.0) using the `@spawn` macro.

I have noticed that using `@spawn` the jobs are actually performed sequentially (albeit from different workers).
This is not happening when using the [pmap][1] function which computes the jobs in parallel.

Following is the code for the `main.jl` program which calls the function (in the module `hello_module`) that should be executed:

```
#### MAIN START ####
# deploy the workers
addprocs(4)
# load modules with multi-core functions
@everywhere include(joinpath(dirname(@__FILE__), "hello_module.jl"))

# number of cores
cpus = nworkers()

# print hello world in parallel
hello_module.parallel_hello_world(cpus)

  [1]: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Distributed/#Distributed.pmap
```

...and here is the code for the module:

```
module hello_module    
using Distributed
using Printf: @printf
using Base

"""Print Hello World on STDOUT"""
function hello_world()
    println("Hello World!")
end

"""Print Hello World in Parallel."""
function parallel_hello_world(threads::Int)

    # create array with as many elements as the threads
    a = [x for x=1:threads]

    #= This would perform the computation in parallel
    wp = WorkerPool(workers())
    c = pmap(hello_world, wp, a, distributed=true)
    =#

    # spawn the jobs
    for t in a
        r = @spawn hello_world()
        # @show r
        s = fetch(r)
    end    
end

end # module end
```

Comment: I provided you with a answer but it would be a great courtesy towards the reader on your side if you could replace `count_proteins` in your code with a `hello_world` function. It will be easier for others to read in the future.

Comment: That is true, I will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use green threading to manage your parallelism. 
In Julia it is achieved by using `@sync` and `@async` macros.
See the minimal working example below:

```
using Distributed

addprocs(3)
@everywhere using Dates
@everywhere function f()
    println("starting at $(myid()) time $(now()) ")
    sleep(1)
    println("finishing at $(myid()) time $(now()) ")
    return myid()^3
end

function test()
    fs = Dict{Int,Future}()
    @sync for w in workers()
        @async fs[w] = @spawnat w f()
    end
    res = Dict{Int,Int}()
    @sync for w in workers()
        @async res[w] = fetch(fs[w])
    end
    res
end
```

And here is the output that clearly shows that the functions are being run in parallel:

```
julia> test()
      From worker 3:    starting at 3 time 2019-04-02T01:18:48.411
      From worker 2:    starting at 2 time 2019-04-02T01:18:48.411
      From worker 4:    starting at 4 time 2019-04-02T01:18:48.415
      From worker 2:    finishing at 2 time 2019-04-02T01:18:49.414
      From worker 3:    finishing at 3 time 2019-04-02T01:18:49.414
      From worker 4:    finishing at 4 time 2019-04-02T01:18:49.418
Dict{Int64,Int64} with 3 entries:
  4 => 64
  2 => 8
  3 => 27
```

EDIT:

I recommend you managing how your computations are allocated. However, you can also use `@spawn`. Note that in the scenario below jobs got getting allocated simultaneously on workers.

```
function test(N::Int)
    fs = Dict{Int,Future}()
    @sync for task in 1:N
        @async fs[task] = @spawn f()
    end
    res = Dict{Int,Int}()
    @sync for task in 1:N
        @async res[task] = fetch(fs[task])
    end
    res
end
```

And here is the output:

```
julia> test(6)
      From worker 2:    starting at 2 time 2019-04-02T10:03:07.332
      From worker 2:    starting at 2 time 2019-04-02T10:03:07.34
      From worker 3:    starting at 3 time 2019-04-02T10:03:07.332
      From worker 3:    starting at 3 time 2019-04-02T10:03:07.34
      From worker 4:    starting at 4 time 2019-04-02T10:03:07.332
      From worker 4:    starting at 4 time 2019-04-02T10:03:07.34
      From worker 4:    finishin at 4 time 2019-04-02T10:03:08.348
      From worker 2:    finishin at 2 time 2019-04-02T10:03:08.348
      From worker 3:    finishin at 3 time 2019-04-02T10:03:08.348
      From worker 3:    finishin at 3 time 2019-04-02T10:03:08.348
      From worker 4:    finishin at 4 time 2019-04-02T10:03:08.348
      From worker 2:    finishin at 2 time 2019-04-02T10:03:08.348
Dict{Int64,Int64} with 6 entries:
  4 => 8
  2 => 27
  3 => 64
  5 => 27
  6 => 64
  1 => 8
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Przemyslaw Szufel.
As you can see from the title, I am using `@spawn` instead of `@spawnat` for which the worker ID is required. Eitherway it would work.
Could you just change `@spawn` and avoid returning the work ids. 

I mean could you fetch without knowing the worker ID?

Comment: Yes you can (I edited the example) but usually it is better to manage that on your own or use `@distributed` loop. Note that worker id is also present in the `.where` field of a `Future` object.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is usually better, but in some cases I might not be needed to know the worker id :)